# how to remove Team Foundation login informations in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I have a project shared in Visual Studio Team Services and I use Visual Studio 2012 Express.

My team mate logged in with a wrong account and now when selecting the server to connect to VS doesn't ask him for credentials any more.

I read that VS credentials in Windows 7 are managed via the control panel -> user account -> credential manager. But even when there are no more credential inside it, rebboting VS, rebooting the computer, he is not asked for login information when selecting the server to use.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing one of the latest versions of IExplorer (because yes, he had not) and using it to delete cache.

I think it would also work to use the control panel to delete cache and cookies, but I wasn't able to find it in windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Have the user log in to TFS using the browser
2. Have the user use the "Sign out" function from the "User" menu (the one with his picture, upper right corner)

This is likely to be more of a Windows ID issue and less of a TFS or Visual Studio issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Connect to Team Foundation Server" box in VS 2012, select the Visual Studio Team Services account from the Servers drop down, and there should be a "Sign Out" link on the bottom left of the box.

Once you click that it will change to "Sign In" and you will have to re-authenticate to connect.

**Example:**
[image]

Comment: My buddy had not the sign out option, because he hadn't successfully signed in. Anyway the browser kept informations about his failed login denyng him to repeat login operation.

He solved right now, I'm posting the working solution